# Load MovieClip at runtime

Tags: flash, apache-flex, load, runtime, movieclip

I created a movie clip, and I wish to load it to flex. But I can't use any of my movie clip properties.

Why?

This is what I did:

```
var loader:Loader;
private function init():void{
   loader = new Loader();
   loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
   loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
   loader.load(new URLRequest("myClip.swf"));
}

private function completeHandler(event:Event):void{
   trace(loader.content.myElement); // getting exception
}
```

In my flash fla file, I create that movie clip, and set instance name for one of the elements - myElement.

Any ideas what it can be?

Answer (score 0):

see if loader.content is indeed loaded, and is a MovieClip.

Comment: Yeah If I add it to stage, I can see it just fine!

Comment: Can you do some checks, like: var mc:MovieClip = loader.content as MovieClip; if(mc && mc.myElement) trace(mc.myElement); ... It could be an error where the myElement symbol is not exported for ActionScript ....

Comment: it's exported indeed, I gave it a costume class, and I did not had any compiler errors in flash pro

Comment: Can you run swfdump and see if that symbol is really there? Can you also post the error you are getting?

Comment: This what I see in debug for the content: myClip_fla.MainTimeline__Preloader__ (@b854821)

Comment: ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property myElement not found on myClip_fla.MainTimeline__Preloader__ and there is no default value.

Comment: this the exception that I am getting when trying access mc.myElement

Comment: That clearly means it wasn't exported. Can you try to re-export the swf again, and clear your browser cache, if applicable.

Comment: If I can see it on the screen, does't it mean that he was exported?! This is not a cache error

Comment: No, it means that it was available as a child of the container, but not exported for runtime access by ActionScript. You should see the instance name and give it a name like myElement ... and give it a valid class.

Comment: did that, may be at the time that I am testing it, it is not ready yet? any ideas?

Comment: Drag that element to stage, give it an instance name, set the element type... Then re-export the SWF and copy it where needed.. Then access it and see if it works. That's pretty much it - routine Flash for you!

Comment: ok I did it, I added click event to the element, after I see that he is created I am clicking on it, and nothing...zzzz. Stupid FLEX!!!